# "The archive is invalid" during archive validation in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer, xcode4.2, ios5

I try to upload an update for my app. However I always get this error message:

[image]

I use xcode 4.2 and the iOS 5.0 SDK. I read that question [Xcode iOS organizer submit to app store yields "The archive is invalid" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483728/xcode-ios-organizer-submit-to-app-store-yields-the-archive-is-invalid-error) but nothing helped.

I tried following

- uninstall xcode using command line and reinstall it
- delete all distribution proviles and create new
- opened the project file in text editor removed all provisioning lines
  and code sign lines, clean and build

I keep getting this error message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Xcode 4.2 beta which cannot submit valid applications to the appstore, since it is beta. I rolled back to xcode 4 and was able to upload my build.

Answer (score 1):

I tried removing CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY from the project file using a text editor with no luck. http://elishaz.tistory.com/entry/The-archive-is-invalid-appipa-does-not-exist

However, try using

`Don't resign`

instead of choosing your distribution profile when submitting in the Organizer.

It worked for me.

Matt