# error: 0xe8003ffe when sync .ipa file ad-hoc distribution from XCODE 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-provisioning, xcode4.2

Drag and drop provisioning profile and ipa file to itune. sync app to iphone and got error: 0xe8003ffe. how I can sync this app to my iphone?  (My iphone is using IOS 4.0) is that the reason of error?? thank you for your answer.

Comment: IME, iPhone Configuration Utility is generally preferable to iTunes.

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306018/the-archive-is-invalid-during-archive-validation-in-xcode

Answer (score 5):

Xcode 4.2 is beta software, which usually means you cannot archive your app for ad-hoc distribution from it.
You need to use Xcode 4.0.2 or Xcode 3 to archive your app for ad-hoc distribution.

If that doesn't help, make sure you have the provision profile you used to codesign the app with dragged into iTunes!