# Validate app for iOS store archive error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, app-store

I'm trying to archive my app for upload to the app store and I can't figure it out for the life of me. I've already submitted a ticket to Apple technical support, but I figured I would try here to see if anyone's seen it before. Couldn't find anything on the internet. I tried manually selecting the correct provisioning profile as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483728/xcode-ios-organizer-submit-to-app-store-yields-the-archive-is-invalid-error).

Error screenshots:

[image]

[image]

When I look in the terminal at said paths, there is no .bcsym and the other one doesn't have Packages/:

[image: First picture path]

[image: Second picture path]

Any ideas? The only weird thing I can think of is that this is a Swift rewrite of an Obj-C app so it's in a totally separate xcodeproj. I also had to rename the project at one point to match the legacy name.

Comment: Check this link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14729. If you are using Xcode 7, disable "Include bitcode for iOS targets" from application. Let me know if this works for you. Please feel free to ask if you need more help.

Comment: Further more, it seems this issue only appears when you build with Xcode 7. I would recommend you to go through **eskerber's** answer  in this link : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14729

Comment: Thanks for the link, Parth. Unchecking the `Include App symbols did it`, feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: If you know why it happened too, that would be great :)

Comment: I think it happened to you as you might have set stripped the symbols from the build settings for the Release mode and hence it is not able to find it. This is just a guess as I have not seen your application's build settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems this issue only appears when you build with Xcode 7. I would recommend you to go through **eskerber's** answer in the below link :

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14729

Just for reference, I am posting the answer from the link here:

> It's likely you built your app with Enable Bitcode set to NO in build
> settings.
>
> Then, in the app submission window, you had "include
> bitcode" checked, which is now at the bottom of the window. Uncheck
> that and it should submit. Enable bitcode in your build settings if
> you want to then submit with bitcode.

Also additionally you may uncheck "Include App symbols did it" from submission window.

Comment: Thank you. I will award the bounty once the cooldown expires.

Comment: @goodcow: I think it happened to you as you might have set stripped the symbols from the build settings for the Release mode and hence it is not able to find it. This is just a guess as I have not seen your application's build settings.

Answer (score 1):

The likely issue is that you build your project with different bitcode settings and uploading with different.
First check in your project settings if you have set the bitcode to yes or no.

[image]

And the while uploading make sure you check the(include bitcode) box only if your bitcode settings was Yes otherwise uncheck it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Related to this issue, you may notice that the app binary is very large if you upload with bitcode, even in Testflight. Apple trims this upon distributing in the app store.